# actionbar homebutton closes app instead of going to prevous activity

Tags: java, android

I have a mainActivity which launches a second activity. when am in the second activity and I press actionbar homebutton it closes the app instead of returning to the mainActivty. note that this only happens if I change the the orientation of the screen in the second activity. this is what I use to go back to the mainActivity;

```
else if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            overridePendingTransition (R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
            finish();
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try placing finish(); before overridePendingTransition,

From the Android API for Activity: overridePendingTransition,

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int,%20int)

Call immediately after one of the flavors of startActivity(Intent) or finish() to specify an explicit transition animation to perform next.

Comment: doesn't work. the problem seems to be related to the orientation change because it works properly if I don't change the orientation in the second activity